# Tag Multiple Files

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, metadata, powerapp

My scenario : I have over 10k files in different sites. They all have the same content type (same amount of columns) and are found in folders/ subfolders. I need an effective and quick way to add the different metadata for those files.

I was thinking to use csom, but i will have to use a recursive function to get to the inner sub folders item and i will have to read each files content type from an excel. I think this approach is over kill to write code from scratch.

Is there another way to accomplish this or at least part of it easily?

Answer (score 1):

Powershell could do that quite easily. It wouldn't be that hard to write.

from: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/07/powershell-to-bulk-update-metadata-from-csv-in-sharepoint-online.html

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
$ListName= "Branding"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\DocMetadata.csv"
 
#Function to get Lookup ID from Lookup Value
Function Get-LookupID($ListName, $LookupFieldName, $LookupValue)
{
    #Get Parent Lookup List and Field from Child Lookup Field's Schema XML
    $LookupField =  Get-PnPField -List $ListName -Identity $LookupFieldName
    [Xml]$Schema = $LookupField.SchemaXml
    $ParentListID = $Schema.Field.Attributes["List"].'#text'
    $ParentField  = $Schema.field.Attributes["ShowField"].'#text'
    $ParentLookupItem  = Get-PnPListItem -List $ParentListID -Fields $ParentField | Where {$_[$ParentField] -eq $LookupValue} | Select -First 1 
    If($ParentLookupItem -ne $Null)  { Return $ParentLookupItem["ID"] }  Else  { Return $Null }
}
 
Try {
    #Connect to SharePoint Online site
    Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
    #Get the data from CSV file
    $CSVData = Import-CSV $CSVFile
 
    #Get fields to Update from the List - Skip Read-only, hidden fields and content type
    $ListFields = Get-PnPField -List $ListName | Where { (-Not ($_.ReadOnlyField)) -and (-Not ($_.Hidden)) -and ($_.InternalName -ne  "ContentType") }
 
    #Loop through each Row in the CSV file and update metadata
    ForEach($Row in $CSVData)
    {
        #Get All columns from CSV - Exclude "FileName" and "ServerRelativeURL" Columns
        $CSVFields = $Row | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Where {$_.Name -notin ("FileName","ServerRelativeURL")}
 
        #Get the File to update
        $File = Get-PnPFile -Url $Row.ServerRelativeURL -AsListItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If($File -ne $Null)
        {
            #Frame the Metadata to update
            $ItemValue = @{}
 
            #Map each field from CSV to target list
            Foreach($CSVField in $CSVFields)
            {
                $MappedField = $ListFields | Where {$_.InternalName -eq $CSVField}
                If($MappedField -ne $Null)
                {
                    $FieldName = $MappedField.InternalName
                    #Check if the Field value is not Null
                    If($Row.$CSVField -ne $Null)
                    {
                        #Handle Special Fields
                        $FieldType  = $MappedField.TypeAsString 
                        If($FieldType -eq "User" -or $FieldType -eq "UserMulti") #People Picker Field
                        {
                            $PeoplePickerValues = $Row.$FieldName.Split(",")
                            $ItemValue.add($FieldName,$PeoplePickerValues)
                        }
                        ElseIf($FieldType -eq "Lookup" -or $FieldType -eq "LookupMulti") #Lookup Field
                        {
                            $LookupIDs = $Row.$FieldName.Split(",") | ForEach-Object { Get-LookupID -ListName $ListName -LookupFieldName $FieldName -LookupValue $_ }                
                            $ItemValue.Add($FieldName,$LookupIDs)
                        }
                        Else
                        {
                            #Get Source Field Value and add to Hashtable
                            $ItemValue.Add($FieldName,$Row.$FieldName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            #Update document properties
            Write-host "Updating Metadata of the File '$($Row.FileName)' at '$($Row.ServerRelativeURL)' with values:"
            $ItemValue | Format-Table
            Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $File.Id -Values $ItemValue | Out-Null
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Host "Could not find File at $($Row.ServerRelativeURL)' , Skipped!" -f Yellow
        }
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharegate, a 3rd party tool, can be used to do that. You can export the metadata into an Excel file, then use the Excel interface, i.e. formulas, VBA, whatever, to change the values. Then upload the changes to the existing files in SharePoint. All this can be done without interfering with authors and time stamps.

I have no affiliation with Sharegate, but I use it almost daily for migrations and bulk editing jobs like this one.